# UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate - Legacy action methods

Tags: ios8

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` methods to work with the documents. 
I have opened the document in a `UIWebview`. I am trying to share the document through email to other users. For that purpose I'm calling `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem` to display the menu item. It's working till iOS 7 versions, but currently I'm testing with iOS8 and getting the following message in the console:

`UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate implements legacy action methods. Please remove them.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also facing the same problem but there is no solution available.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using at least one of these 2 methods?

```
- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller canPerformAction:(SEL)action NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_2, 6_0);
- (BOOL)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller performAction:(SEL)action NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_2, 6_0);
```

They are deprecated from 6.0. Try not to use them.